# Trouble with Ajax toolkit CalendarExtender Crashes IE6

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax

I have a weird problem with the CalandarExtender on my web project.
When someone click on the little calandar icon IE6 crash! 
I think i properly implemented it

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" 
            TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateDebut" runat="server"
             CssClass="TextBox"></asp:TextBox>  &nbsp;
<asp:ImageButton ID="txtDateDebutButton" runat="server" 
                 ImageUrl="~/images/16X16_2/cal.gif" />
 <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="txtDateDebutCalendarExtender" runat="server" 
                       Animated="false" CssClass="Calendar"
                       FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" 
                       Format="dd/MM/yyyy"
                       PopupButtonID="txtDateDebutButton"  
                       TargetControlID="txtDateDebut">  
 </cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

On have IE7 it works but it stretch up, on IE6 it freeze the app until its stop without any error message.

Comment: Define "IE6 crash" please.  It would help to know the exact behavior.  Does it simply cause the app to quit, is there an error message or some sort, anything will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to try:

1) If you're running this inside of an `UpdatePanel`, make sure your UpdatePanel has an ID set on it.

2) If you have set `EnableEventValidation="false"`, try turning it back `on`.

I know those sound weird, but #2 fixed a crash in IE6 in a very complicated web application that I work on...

Comment: Thank you for the answer i dont have the web project under the nose but when i get to work i'll try this write away and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to step outside the world of what asp.net gives you, you have lots of options such as this:

http://www.stefanoverna.com/log/create-astonishing-ical-like-calendars-with-jquery

Having said that, are you simply trying to make a date picker and want a proper asp.net control, i've used these guys before and it works great (no i dont work there)

http://www.basicdatepicker.com/